# print the abc with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hello I have a problem in my program, the program should print the abc with pointers

The code-

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
for( p ; p < p + len ; p++ )
{
    printf("%c", *p);
}
printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
char* abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
printArray(abc, 26);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me understand the problem, I appreciate it very much

Comment: p<p+len is always true

Answer (score 6):

try

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    while(len--)
        printf("%c", *p++);
    printf("\n");
}
```

or in true k&R style

```
void printArray(char *p)
{
    while(*p) printf("%c",*p++);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char* array)
{
   while(*array)
   {
      printf("%c",*array++);
   }    
   printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
   char* temp = "abcdef";
   print(temp);
   return 0;
}
```

No `len` required.

How does this work? Well, since `char * temp` is null-terminated, the while loop will go until it reaches the null-terminating character (`0`) and `while(0)` is false, so it quits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different variable for the iteration:

```
for (char *cur = p; cur < p + len; cur++) {
    printf("%c", cur);
}
```